# Proving that a rational function is monotonically nondecreasing in Coq

Tags: coq

I have a question about proving that a function nat -> QArith.Q (rationals as of Coq's standard library) is monotonic (always nondecreasing) as part of an exercise about working with rationals in Coq. The problem is that I am stuck in the induction step of the proving process. Suppose I have defined a function as follows.

```
Definition silly (n:nat) : QArith_base.Q :=
    match n with
    | 0 => 1#1 
    | 1 => 2#1
    | 2 => 3#1
    | 3 => 4#1
    | 4 => 5#1
    | 5 => 6#1
    | S n =>  Z.of_N (N.of_nat(S n)) + 7#1
    end.
```

Where N.of_nat is a definition that formalizes natural numbers in a binary way (https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.NArith.BinNatDef.html) by means of the positive inductive type (https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.BinNums.html#N). Z.of_N builds an integer as of Z library, which will be used by Q's constructor, Qmake, to build a rational number. I've defined this way so it would be "easier to define" the function (at least this was what i thought).

Let's say I want to prove the following:

`Lemma sillyIsNondecrescent : forall n, Qle (silly n) (silly(S n))`, Qle the boolean less or equal for Q.

The proof proceeds fine until I hit the (S n) branch, which gives me the following subgoal:

```
(silly (S n) <= silly (S (S n)))%Q
```

which is OK since i'm proving it by induction, then the proof context is

```
n : nat
IHn : (silly n <= silly (S n))%Q
______________________________________(1/1)
(silly (S n) <= silly (S (S n)))%Q
```

I proceed then by unfolding silly's definition. The goal unfolds to:

```
(match n with
 | 0 => 5 # 1
 | 1 => 8 # 1
 | 2 => 11 # 1
 | 3 => 14 # 1
 | 4 => 17 # 1
 | S (S (S (S (S _)))) => Z.of_N (N.of_nat (S n)) + 16 # 1
 end <=
 match n with
 | 0 => 8 # 1
 | 1 => 11 # 1
 | 2 => 14 # 1
 | 3 => 17 # 1
 | S (S (S (S _))) => Z.of_N (N.of_nat (S (S n))) + 16 # 1
 end)%Q
```

I then proceed by case analysis on N, until I reach the Successor branch. The proof stage now is

```
n : nat
IHn : (silly n <= silly (S n))%Q
n0, n1, n2, n3, n4 : nat
______________________________________(1/1)
(Z.of_N (N.of_nat (S (S (S (S (S (S n4))))))) + 16 # 1 <=
 Z.of_N (N.of_nat (S (S (S (S (S (S (S n4)))))))) + 16 # 1)%Q
```

By unfolding N.of_nat, the goal is

```
(match N.of_nat (S (S (S (S (S (S n4)))))) with
 | 0%N => 0
 | N.pos p => Z.pos p
 end + 16 # 1 <=
 match N.of_nat (S (S (S (S (S (S (S n4))))))) with
 | 0%N => 0
 | N.pos p => Z.pos p
 end + 16 # 1)%Q
```

and this is the point i'm getting stuck. No case anaylsis on n4 or destructing n4 here will do because it will generate two goals, each for each constructor of nat (which is the expected by those tactics).

How can i proceed from this point? Is there an prettier way to proceed with proofs similar to this one? Did i define the function in a wrong manner?

I feel that I am missing something quite simple. Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Erick.

EDIT: following Arthur's answer, silly is redefined as

```
silly (n:nat) : QArith_base.Q :=
    if Nat.leb n 5 then Z.of_nat (S n)#1 else Z.of_nat (S n) + 7#1
```

consider the following proof approach:

```
Lemma sillyIsNondecrescent : forall n, Qle (silly n) (silly (S n)).
  Proof.
    intros. case_eq (Nat.leb n 5).
    - intros. unfold silly. rewrite H0. case_eq (Nat.leb (S n) 5).
    + intros.
```

yields me the following context:

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
H0 : (n <=? 5) = true
H1 : (S n <=? 5) = true
______________________________________(1/1)
(Z.of_nat (S n) # 1 <= Z.of_nat (S (S n)) # 1)%Q
```

which falls back to a similar situation as of the initial one presented here. I If i explicitely know "n", Coq (obviously) will know how to solve this goal. Otherwise i get stuck. Did i formalize the Lemma correctly? I'm thinking about rewriting it in terms of "Qeq_bool" which is defined in the same library (Q) as

```
Definition Qeq_bool x y :=
  (Zeq_bool (Qnum x * QDen y) (Qnum y * QDen x))%Z.
```

Any ideias?

Comment: Just a small remark: instead of `Z.of_N (N.of_nat n)`, you can use `Z.of_nat n` directly.

Comment: And you may take advantage of the result of `Search` queries, such as: `Search (Z.of_nat _ <= _)%Z.`

Comment: @eponier thanks for the first tip! Didn't know about that one. As for the search pattern you pointed, I don't think it will be too useful because the comparison is between numbers on Q. But thanks, that gave me an idea of searching for lemmas in Q.

Comment: You should look at the definition of `Qle`.

Comment: Definitely, I'm sorry, that was pretty foolish of me. Using this lemma was a key part. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, a proof by induction is appropriate when the object you want to reason about is defined recursively in terms of the predecessor of a number.  Here, there is no recursive pattern, so induction will hardly help. I think it would be easier to proceed as follows:

1. Redefine `silly` as

   ```
   silly n := if n <= 5 then S n
              else n + 7
   ```

   (Inserting coercions as appropriate to make this valid Coq.)
2. Prove that `silly` is monotonic by considering separately the cases `n < 5`, `n = 5`, and `n > 5`.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks (again). This will work!. Did the way I defined it made things more difficult to deal with because of definitions N.of_nat and Z.of_n? Of course the example you brought is waay simpler, just so i can understand. Since you're here, is there any diference (performance, etc) in using ssreflect's rat library rather than Coq's standard library? i've read a bit about it and it seems quite more understandable than the definitions presented by Coq's standard library.

Comment: @ErickGrilo The cast functions are not so much the issue, but the way you branched on `n`. The rational library in ssreflect is not efficient, because it represents natural numbers in unary form, and because it forces the numerator and the denominator to be relatively prime in every computation. On the other hand, it is much more convenient for reasoning, since it uses the correct notion of equality.

Comment: Hi @Arthur, I've rewritten silly as you suggested but I think I don't know exactly how to branch the proof into the three cases you suggested. The only tactic that i know that coerces some value is case_eq (a == b) which introduces both a == b and a  <> b in the proof context (each one with the same goal). Most of the proofs I've carried on so far were upon definition regarding types on its own (i.e., forall n: nat or forall l: list), not considering values belonging to the type, rather proofs relying on their constructor. I have updated the question with the new scenario. Once again, Thanks!

Comment: @ErickGrilo besides what eponier suggested above, you can also look for lemmas that allow you to convert from `n <=? m = true` to `n <= m`. Tactics like `omega` or `lia` can be used to automate low-level arithmetic reasoning (for instance, showing that `n < 5 \/ n = 5 \/ n > 5`.

Comment: Indeed, it worked! Thanks a lot, both of you! That was pretty dumb of me for not searching for already proved lemmas. I guess it's the first step to do when starting a proof.